# Website meta tag, special characters

Tags: facebook, tags, character, special-characters, meta

Our website meta tag contains special characters such as "í and é" and when I share the website on Facebook the special characters show in a weird way, image attached. How can this be fixed?
[image]

Comment: That is obviously some character encoding problem. What’s the encoding your site uses?

Comment: where can i change the encoding? The developer doesn't answer and its fairly urgent. The site is made up of php files

Comment: Depending on how your site is build, this might be a broader operation, and not done by changing one single thing. I suggest you start by reading http://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/1427878 to get a feel for where the character encoding comes into play. Make backups, before you change anything.

Answer (score 1):

1. Include the Open Graph XML namespace extension to your HTML declaration

< html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">

2. Inside your  use the following meta tag to define the image you want to use

< meta property="og:image" content="your_image_here" />

3.Visit https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ and follow the instructions to change the final image for the preview.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help. Where should I include the Open Graph XML namespace extension?

Comment: The site is made up of php files, it was made by our developer originally but i cant reach him now and it needs to be fixed ASAP... :/